# How would I go about creating a definition application in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

So i'm sort of new to Android development, but have knowledge over it. Basically I'm trying to create an application that displays terms in a list view and then on click opens up another window to the definition for the term. At the moment I have a listview as such:

```
static final String[] DEFINITIONS = new String[] { "Andrew Jackson", "Some other famous guy", "Slavery y'know"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // no more this
    // setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list,DEFINITIONS));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I'm kind of confused on where to go from here. I don't know if i'm going about this in the most efficient way

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your problem. Other than being generally confused, what is the specific problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Start another `Activity` In `OnItemClickListener` which display definition with reference to current selected Item.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Definition.class);
mIntent.putExtra("terms", ((TextView) view).getText());
startActivity(mIntent);
```

In Other end You can get selected terms in your Definition class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String selectedTerms;

if (extras != null) {
    selectedTerms= extras.getString("terms");
}
```

Now You have Selected Terms.Do your stuff now.